# Apply a ggplot-function per group with dplyr and set title per group

Tags: r, split, ggplot2, dplyr

I would like to create one separate plot per group in a data frame and include the group in the title.

With the iris dataset I can in base R and ggplot do this

```
plots1 <- lapply(split(iris, iris$Species), 
  function(x) 
    ggplot(x, aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length)) +
      geom_point() +
      ggtitle(x$Species[1]))
```

Is there an equivalent using dplyr?

Here's an attempt using facets instead of title.

```
p <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
plots2 = iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(plots = p %+% . + facet_wrap(~Species))
```

where I use %+% to replace the dataset in p with the subset for each call.

[image: Workaround with facets]

or (working but complex) with ggtitle

```
plots3 = iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(
    plots = ggplot(data=.) +
      geom_point(aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length)) +
      ggtitle(. %>% select(Species) %>% mutate(Species=as.character(Species)) %>% head(1) %>% as.character()))
```

[image: Working example]

The problem is that I can't seem to set the title per group with ggtitle in a very simple way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `.$Species` to pull the species data into `ggtitle`:

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(plots=ggplot(data=.) +
         aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length) + geom_point() + ggtitle(unique(.$Species)))
```

Comment: I tend to solve this problem via a custom-function where I use `species[1]` to specify the title. But if your actual plot is this simple, this certainly works. IE--my workflow is often `plot.cust <- function(...); iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% plot.cust(...)`

Comment: Very simple solution, did not occur to me! Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewPlourde I suppose so, but it looks a bit clearer than `.$Species[1]`.

Comment: You could also use dplyr-like `first(.$Species)`

Comment: Actually just using ggtitle(.$Species) seems to work, but I don't know why, and I haven't checked the speed of any of the suggestions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 17):

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

plots3 <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  group_map(~ ggplot(.) + aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length) + geom_point() + ggtitle(.y[[1]]))

length(plots3)
#> [1] 3
# for example, the second plot :
plots3[[2]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Interesting to learn about group_map, though I found this didn't work with dplyr 0.8.3, plots3 returns 3 1x1 tibbles. For the last line I think it should be plots3[[2]]$plots. If one wanted to save those plots within the pipe, you think that's possible? Or better to loop through plots3[[n]]$plots ? Cheers!

Comment: What's `.y` in `ggtitle`? I guess it contains information about the different groups? Where does the name `y` come in and how can I access it?

Comment: `.y` is a tibble with exactly one row and columns for each grouping variable, see the doc. So here I take the content of the first and only column, which is the name.

Comment: This solution needs updating.

Comment: Sorry all, I was too quick with my edit, now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This is another option using `rowwise`:

```
plots2 = iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    do(plots = p %+% .) %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    do(x=.$plots + ggtitle(.$Species))
```