# find grouping variable(s) from within a function called by do()

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to call a plotting function on subgroups of a data.frame with `dplyr::do()`, producing one figure (ggplot object) per subgroup. I
want the title of each figure based on the grouping variable. To do this, my function needs to know what the grouping variable is.

Currently, what gets passed to `do()` as `.` is an object of class `tbl_df`
 and `data.frame`. Without explicitly passing it as a separate variable, is there a way to inspect the data.frame directly to learn what was the grouping variable(s) is/are?

The solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034863/apply-a-ggplot-function-per-group-with-dplyr-and-set-title-per-group?rq=1) calls for explicitly passing (each of) the grouping variables as an additional argument to the function. I'm wondering if there is a a more, elegant and general solution that is scaleable to varying numbers of grouping variables. While in this specific instance i'm interested in plotting, there are other other use cases where I want to know how the subgroups are defined from within the function called on each subgroup.

I don't want to want to guess by looking for columns where the
`length(unique(col)) == 1` because that is going to lead to lots of false
positives with my data.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Here is some sample code to get started.

```
library(ggplot2)
my_plot <- function(df) {
  subgroup_name <- "" # ??
  ggplot(aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_point() +
    ggtitle(subgroup_name)
}

 mpg %>%
   group_by(manufacturer) %>%
   do(my_plots = my_plot(.))
```

Comment: You have tried `facet_wrap` already, right? If you really need separate plots, you could `lapply` your plotting function across your data.frame `split` by the grouping variables, though there are certainly other approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think its possible to do this without passing the names of the grouping variable(s) into the function (I think the grouping variable "vars" attribute is lost after splitting the grouped_df data.frame, before executing the "do"). Here's an alternative solution that requires defining the grouping variable(s) in a vector before applying the dplyr group_by %>% do chain:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

my_plot <- function(df, group_vars) {

    # get plot name from value(s) in grouping variable(s)
    subgroup_name <- paste(df[1, group_vars], collapse = " ")

    ggplot(data = df, aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(subgroup_name)

}


group1 <- "manufacturer"
plots1 <- 
    mpg %>% 
    group_by_(.dots = group1) %>%
    do(my_plots = my_plot(., group1))
plots1$my_plots[1]
```

[image]

```
group2 <- c("manufacturer", "year")
plots2 <- 
    mpg %>% 
    group_by_(.dots = group2) %>%
    do(my_plots = my_plot(., group2))
plots2$my_plots[2]
```

[image]